# GWT set button text inline

Tags: button, gwt

GWT 2.7
How can I set inline text in GWT Button

```
Button b = new Button("Inline Text");
```

I don't want text on 2 lines into the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the button a width:

```
button.setWidth("200px");
```

so that the button has enough space to display the text in one line.

Or you can add a stylesheet with:

```
button.addStyleName("myStyle");
```

and this stylesheets contains the line:

```
.myStyle { white-space: nowrap; }
```

This should work.

Comment: It works! I try to use:   button.getElement().getStyle().setWhiteSpace(WhiteSpace.NOWRAP);
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Uglier, but easier ;-) you could replace blanks in your string label with `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`:

```
Button b = new Button("Inline&nbsp;Text");
```